# MSP-EXP432 "Analog In" pin taking voltage from circuit

Tags: analog, adc, ldr, photoresistor, energia

[image]I am building a circuit consisting of a voltage divider (with a fixed resistor and a LDR or photoresistor) outputting voltage to an ADC.

I want to measure the voltage going to the ADC using an MSP-EXP432 ; however, the MSP-EXP432 "Analog In" pin is taking voltage from the circuit (i.e. the voltage going into the ADC drops when the "Analog In" pin is connected).

I set the pin as an input in the code shown below in Energia.

```
const int bitsOfADC = 14; // 14-bit ADC Launchpad
//int maxVal = 2^N -1; 
// 2^14-1
int maxVal = 16383;
float FSV = 5.0; // Supply to 0804ADC
float LaunchPadResolution = FSV/maxVal;
int D7 = A13;
int D6 = A14;
int ADCInput = A6;
boolean D7_State = LOW;
boolean D6_State = LOW;
void setup()
{
  delay(1000);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(D7, INPUT);
  pinMode(D6, INPUT);
  analogReadResolution(bitsOfADC);
  pinMode(ADCInput, INPUT);
}
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: What kind of Arduino uses an MSP430 processor? My guess is that you haven't configured the analog input pin correctly, or that there is a wiring error.

Comment: Your load is R4 =1k.  The only way I see analog inputs loading that is ESD damage.

Comment: You are far better using a Panasonic Light sensor which is logarithmic, CIE corrected  and spanning > 4decades in a low cost 5mm package T1-3/4  Your design appears to indicate  8 quasi linear levels

Comment: How is configured in software the analog pin (adc input) of MSPEXP432?

Comment: Don't put a screenshot of your code into the question. Add the code as text and then format it as a code block.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the analog input pin has been configured as an analog input. If you don't, the digital circuitry will interfere with the analog function.

For the MSP432 this is typically done by setting bits in the Px.SEL0 and Px.SEL1 registers. If the analog input is bit *y* on port *x* then you need something like

```
Px->SEL0 |= BITy;
Px->SEL1 |= BITy;
```

All of the identifiers used will be defined in `msp.h`.

Comment: Can this be done from the coding IDE? (i.e. Energia, in this case) Or is it done in the files themselves? If it is done in the files, do you know which file contains these registers?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "in the files". The registers are not **contained** in any file. I use Code Composer Studio but the answer would apply equally well to gcc. If you were specifically asking about Energia you should have said so in your question, rather than talking about the Arduino.

Comment: I edited the post to include more accurate information, including code. Is the pin correctly configured as an input?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Energia. You should probably find a forum for Energia users and ask there.

Comment: Energia would probably use an Arduino like approach to pin configuration... That is basically the point of it.  However analog and digital input modes can be different in in unique ways on different hardware.